# VS2008 Error After installing TFS Powertools

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs

I'm getting a weird error occassionally in VS2008. A colleague gets a similar error, we both noticed it after installing TFS PowerToys so I'm wondering if it's related.

Anyway the error is:

Team Foundation Error
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID{GUIID...} failed due to the following error: 80040154,

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS Power tools installs something to be able to inform developers using MSN Messenger and this error is caused by MSN Messenger. Maybe this should help [MSN Messenger Errors 80040111 and 80040154](http://msn-errors.blogspot.com/2006/11/msn-messenger-errors-80040111-and.html)

> Fix 80040111 and 80040154 Error.
>
> Cause: MSXML library may be corrupted and may have to be reinstalled
>
> Troubleshooting steps:
>
> Step 1. Re-register msxml3.dll
>
> - Click on the Start menu, select Run and type the following:
>   **Regsvr32 %windir%\system32\msxml3.dll**
>
> Hopefully, you will see a window popup that says: 
> **DllRegisterServer succeeded in C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll is succeeded.**
>
> Step 2. Restart your computer and sign into Messenger again

Comment: This didn't work for me. But deactivating Team Explorer integration with Messensger as described in an answer below by Myles worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

Team Explorer has collaboration facilities to allow it to interact with Windows Live Messenger or Office Communicator.  If you've uninstalled these, you might get the same error from Team Explorer trying to talk to a non existent program.  In Team Explorer, right click on Team Members, click Personal Settings.  Under Collaboration, click change and choose  (or put it to another provider if you wish).

This worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me. The official answer did not. Thanks :)

Comment: Me too; the official answer assumes we have messenger installed. My error didn't come until I uninstalled messenger.

Answer (score 0):

We recently changed from SourceSafe to TFS at my workplace and a good bunch of us had to reinstall SP1 in VS2008 to get Powertools and TFS to work properly. Wheter this is related to your problem however I am unsure... It did seem to clear up several weird errors for me.